# Does the flag kSecAttrAccessControl has an effect on the public key when generating the key pair using SecKeyGeneratePair?

Tags: ios, swift, security, keychain

I am creating a private/public key pair using the SecKeyGeneratePair method.
To be able to do that I create a parameter dictionary with kSecPrivateKeyAttrs and kSecPublicKeyAttrs.
In the kSecPrivateKeyAttrs and kSecPublicKeyAttrs (both a dictionary) I add kSecAttrAccessControl to set the protection level of the key (eg. kSecAttrAccessibleAfterFirstUnlockThisDeviceOnly).

```
var publicKey, privateKey: SecKey?            
let status = SecKeyGeneratePair(params as CFDictionary, &publicKey, &privateKey)
```

The generation of the keys succeeds but it seams that adding the kSecAttrAccessControl only affects the private key.
Is this documented somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find any documentation but what you observe makes sense based on a few things:

- Keychain APIs store secrets on Apple's platforms. The public key is not a secret. Only the private key is. So it makes sense that data protection would only apply to the private key.
- The keychain on iOS is similar to Keychain Access on macOS. In Keychain Access, only private keys have access controls. See attached. That's my for my distribution private key.

[image]